# How to avoid new line character in Json response In Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have created a Spring boot application that will provide PGP Secret KEY details including actual key Data.

**Original Data:**

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG v1.68
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=t3Hn
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

**JSON RESPONSE DATA**

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----\nVersion: BCPG v1.68\n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\nUEpEw5SDnbEO/tyX5AxaycJ6uMRqFBl5tT8JWw==\n=t3Hn\n-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----\n"
```

**NOTE** Please refer to original data and JSON response data

the problem is that when we were passing the data in JSON response we were getting `\n` in the data and that is modifying the original data. Is there any way that we can handle the JSON without appending `\n`?

Comment: "*provide PGP Secret KEY*" - Don't. Just... no. Do NOT provide secret keys online. Do not store them (unencrypted) online.

Comment: Yeah Sure and here PGP Secret KEY is Dev testing not for use.

Comment: Well, this is not JSON… so maybe try to set the`Content-Type` to something like `text/plain`…